# Showing that the ring $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{2}]$ has exactly $2$ automorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, automorphism-group

Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:

> [image]

I am wondering:

1- Why this proof shows that the ring $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{2}]$ has exactly $2$ automorphisms? Could anyone explain this to me, please?

2- What are the general steps of finding all automorphisms of a ring and confirming that they are all?

Comment: This ring is generated by the integer $1$ and the element $\sqrt{2}$. Any automorphism (or any homomorphism for that matter) of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is determined by where the automorphism sends $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$. This narrows the number of possible automorphisms down a lot.

Comment: For (1), the ring is generated by $\sqrt{2}$, and so an automorphism is completely determined by where it sends this element.  For (2), you would want to find a collection of generators, and determine where they could possibly be sent.  If they satisfy an algebraic relation, then so do their images.

Comment: From $\phi(m+n\sqrt{2}) = \phi(m) + \phi(n)\phi(\sqrt{2})$, if you know $\phi$ on $\mathbf Z$ and $\sqrt{2}$ then you know $\phi$ everywhere. Show $\varphi(a) = a$ for all $a \in \mathbf Z$ using induction. Then show $\phi(\sqrt{2})$ can only take two possible values, namely $\pm\sqrt{2}$, so either $\phi(m+n\sqrt{2}) = m+n\sqrt{2}$ for all integers $m$ and $n$, or $\phi(m+n\sqrt{2}) = m-n\sqrt{2}$ for all integers $m$ and $n$.  That shows there are *at most two* choices for $\phi$ (identity of conjugation). Check both are ring homomorphisms equal to their inverse, so they're automorphism.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [See here for an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742). Use MathJax to typeset, instead.

Comment: There is no *general* method of determining all the automorphisms of a ring, just as there is no general method to determine all the automorphisms of a group. In specific cases you may be able to succeed, but in general it's hopeless to describe the automorphisms of a completely general ring (or group).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok, sorry about that.

Comment: @KCd what are the specific cases in which I may succeed?

Comment: @Empymind. You can do it for fields to a certain extend. Take a look at Galois-theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question no. 1, if $\phi:\mathbb Z[\sqrt2] \longrightarrow \mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$ is an automorphism, then $\phi$ will be an automorphism on $\mathbb Z$ too. From the definition of ring homomorphism, we can write $\phi(m + n \sqrt 2) = \phi(m)+\phi(n)\phi(\sqrt 2)$. Now, find automorphisms on $\mathbb Z$. They are precisely $n \longmapsto n$ (since for any ring homomorphism, $1 \longmapsto 1$). Hence $\phi(m+n\sqrt 2) = m+n\phi(\sqrt 2)$. Your book says clearly why $\phi(\sqrt 2) = \pm\sqrt 2$.

To answer your question no. 2, at first take $1 \longmapsto 1$. It eases things. Usually we come across rings in the form of $R[\xi]$ where $\xi$ is from some bigger ring containing $R$, $R$ is some arbitrary ring. Generally we take $R$ as unital and commutative, hence $R$ contains $\mathbb Z$ as a subring and hence in $R$, $a \longmapsto a$. Now if $\xi$ is algebraic/integral on $R$, take the minimal polynomial of $\xi$ over $R$ and check if you take $\xi$ to its roots, whether they give you automorphisms or not. If $\xi$ is transcendental, then I think we just have one choice, $\xi \longmapsto \xi$, although I'm not quite sure about it.